# Why won't my PHP mail() function send it with the correct linebreaks?

Tags: php

Code is below. I want it to separate the [From: xxxxxx] part so the rest of the body/message appears on a different line.

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $recipient = "me@christianselig.com";
    $subject = "Message From Website";
    $body = "[From: " . $name . "]\n\n" . $message;
    $headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    $success = mail($recipient, $subject, $body, $headers);

    echo $success;

?>
```

Comment: Sending from Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the HTML tag `<br />` instead of  `\n`

Like this:

```
$body = "[From: " . $name . "]<br /><br />" . $message;
```

And a suggestion using the `mail()` function:

```
if( mail($recipient, $subject, $body, $headers) )
    echo 'Success';
else
    echo 'Fail';
```

**EDIT 1**

As you are trying to send as plain text you should use `\r\n`, this is the escape sequence for new line in plain text. Example:

```
$formcontent="[From: " . $name . "]\r\n\r\n" . $message;
```

Comment: Well, I check the value of success in my JavaScript, so I kind of like it as is.

Comment: Also, it's sent as plaintext not HTML.

Comment: @DougSmith, Please see the Edit 1

Comment: There's also a downside in using HTML; as it increases the chances of the email getting flagged by spam filters.